# How listen for specific child change in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to do something if a user has new lat or long data.

And I want to do something else if a user has new text data.

Currently I can only detect if a user has any of this changes.

(I want to listen for changes without knowing the userID of the user)

```
const usersRef = ref(db, 'users/');

// If user has new values
onChildChanged(usersRef, (data) => {
    if (data.val().userID != myUserId) {
        console.log("User with userID: " + data.val().userID + "\n"
            + "has new coordinates or text" + "\n"
            + "lat: " + data.val().lat + "\n"
            + "long: " + data.val().long);
        updateMarker(data.val().userID, data.val().lat, data.val().long);
        // If user has new text
        if (data.child("text").exists()) {
            console.log("new text: " + data.val().text);
            updateMarkerText(data.val().userID, data.val().text);
        }
    }
});
```

This is my database structure:
[image]

Comment: _"I want to listen for changes without knowing the userID of the user"_ What do you know about the user? There must be some reference so you can get a specific users information.

Comment: If any user (without knowing his userID) has new lat/long data I want to call function1 and pass his new lat/long data and his userID. And if any user (without knowing his userID) has new text data I want to call function2 and pass his new text data and his userID.

Comment: If you want to call the code for any user, remove the `if (data.val().userID != myUserId) {` condition.